# Diseño de Impresion ReportView C#

Tags: c#, reportviewer

llevo un buen rato buscando solucion para esto, espero me puedan ayudar.

Tengo la siguiente vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo Cual esta bien, pero al usuario final me gustaria mostrarle el diseño en hoja:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual consegui clickeando en diseño de impresion.

> Lo que me gustaria hacer por codigo y no dejar que el usuario final este clikeando cada ves que saque el reporte.

El codigo donde envio parametros es el Load del formulario:

```
 private void FromViewReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomerSourceReportUno rpt = new CustomerSourceReportUno();
        DataTable factura = CFacturar.MostrarID(id);
        DataTable infomacion = CInformacion.Mostrar();
        DataTable cliente = CCliente.MostrarID(factura.Rows[0][1].ToString());
        var customer = rpt.getList(this.id);
        this.MReporteUnoBindingSource.DataSource = customer;
        ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[16];
        string path = "file:\\" + Application.StartupPath + "\\ImagenEmpresarial.jpg";
        string pathqr = "file:\\" + Application.StartupPath + "\\qrs\\" + factura.Rows[0][4].ToString() + ".jpg";
        parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("Path", @path,true);
        parameters[1] = new ReportParameter("PathQr", @pathqr ,true);
        parameters[2] = new ReportParameter("empresa", infomacion.Rows[0][1].ToString());
        parameters[3] = new ReportParameter("propietario", infomacion.Rows[0][4].ToString());
        parameters[4] = new ReportParameter("direccion", infomacion.Rows[0][2].ToString());
        parameters[5] = new ReportParameter("nit", infomacion.Rows[0][5].ToString());
        parameters[6] = new ReportParameter("nro", id);
        parameters[7] = new ReportParameter("autorizacion", infomacion.Rows[0][6].ToString());
        parameters[8] = new ReportParameter("telefono", infomacion.Rows[0][3].ToString());
        parameters[9] = new ReportParameter("literal", factura.Rows[0][6].ToString());
        parameters[10] = new ReportParameter("nombre_cliente",cliente.Rows[0][2].ToString());
        parameters[11] = new ReportParameter("ci", cliente.Rows[0][1].ToString());
        parameters[12] = new ReportParameter("fecha", factura.Rows[0][2].ToString());
        parameters[13] = new ReportParameter("total", factura.Rows[0][3].ToString());
        parameters[14] = new ReportParameter("codigo_control", factura.Rows[0][4].ToString());
        parameters[15] = new ReportParameter("fecha_limite", factura.Rows[0][5].ToString());
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

Comment: Intenta añadir `this.reportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout)`

Comment: Y como seria para la version web? this.reportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout);

Comment: Pues no estoy seguro como se lo pueda hacer en web, deberias de abrir una nueva pregunta para que alguien te pueda ayudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método [`SetDisplayMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.setdisplaymode.aspx) de `ReportViewer`:

```
this.reportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

En código visual basic a mi me funcionó esto. Para VB web debe ser igual o similar.

```
ReportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
```

Comment: Cuál es **la diferencia**, entre esta respuesta y la [respuesta aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/146208/69447)???